# Print shortcode according to site language

Tags: shortcode, language

I'm creating my website with "elementor plugin". So I used to customize the default WordPress search result page since I couldn't access it with elementor.

Anyway, I tried to display my custom elementor footer using a short code:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[INSERT_ELEMENTOR id='319']"); ?>
```

The code above displays my footer in Arabic version.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[INSERT_ELEMENTOR id='3183"]'); ?>
```

And this one above is for English version.

How can I switch to any custom footer I want according to site language?

Answer (score 0):

That's probably basic PHP. As all that's needed would be some kind of map/array and then switch use the `id` according to what [`get_locale()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_locale) returns.

```
<?php

// Provide a map if locales and shortcode IDs.
$custom_footer = [
  'ar'    => '319',
  'en_US' => '3181',
  // ... and so on
];

// Get the current language.
$current_language = get_locale();

// Get the right shortcode ID.
$shortcode_id = $custom_footer[$current_language];

?>

<?php echo "Just for debugging, the current language is: " . $current_language; ?>

<?php echo do_shortcode("[INSERT_ELEMENTOR id='" . $shortcode_id . "']"); ?>
```